# Getting margin-top of element whilst being animated

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I am animating an element with the top margin. However, when said element reaches a certain margin, I want to create another event. I did what I assumed would work, but it doesnt seem to be doing anything.

So I have an element moving to margin top 300px, and when it hits 300px I want it to got to margin-top -80px.

```
function raindrop(element,speed) {
    $(element).animate({
        'margin-top':'300px'
    }, speed, 'linear');
    margin = parseInt($(element).css('marginTop'));
    if(margin>=300) {
        $(element).css('marginTop','-80px');
            $(element).animate({
        'margin-top':'300px'
    }, speed, 'linear');
    }
}
```

I also want to use a re-cursive function here so it keeps doing it. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use ["complete" callback function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-duration-easing-complete) in jQuery's `animate()`, which is a *function to call once the animation is complete*.

Comment: @VivianKennedy, I would like to suggest you to look into [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) API for animating elements in a *linear* fashion. I humbly believe, there is no need to do what you are trying to do using `animate()` function of jQuery. But I also know that it is a very subjective matter, a *taste* thing. It is always good to know available options.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any if statement in your code to check the condition because if statement executes before the animation completes. Instead of if, better to use a callback function which will only execute after the first animation finishes. In callback, you can move your element back to margin-top:-80px once it reaches at 300px. If you also want to do recursion then you can call your raindrop() function as a callback function of second animation which does infinite looping. Here is the modified code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn").click(function () {
        raindrop("#mydiv", 1000);
    });
});

function raindrop(element, speed) {
    $(element).animate({
        'margin-top': '300px'
    }, speed, 'linear', function () {
        margin = parseInt($(element).css('marginTop'));
        //alert(margin);
        $(element).animate({
            'margin-top': '-80px'
        }, speed, 'linear', raindrop(element, speed));
    });
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#mydiv
{
    border:1px solid red;
    width:300px;
    height:150px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Press">
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```